# resize css rule changes other divs

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have several divs with css rule 'resize: both' on all of them. The problem is that when I start to resize any of them others move automatically. Is is possible to change that behaviour?

Tried 'position: absolute' but it isn't a solution, cause it collects all divs in one place. They are also will be draggable like notes, so I can't stick them to corners.

The resizable div should change its size over the others (with higher z-index or smth like this). Others should stay at their positions while resizing and after

code: https://jsfiddle.net/q3m5ya8f/

```css
.el {
  resize: both;
  overflow-y: auto;
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="el">
    1
  </div>

  <div class="el">
    2
  </div>

</div>


<div class="el">
  3
</div>
```

[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EiGbT.png)

Comment: how do you want your divs to behave?

Comment: The resizable div should change its size over the others (with higher z-index or smth like this). Others should stay at their positions while resizing and after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can achieve this by `position:absolute` and position each of `div` using `left/right/top/bottom` properties separately like done in bellow snippet ( position can be your desired one I have taken for example ) :

```css
.el {
  resize: both;
  overflow-y: auto;
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute
}

.el1 {
  left: 0
}

.el2 {
  right: 0
}

.el3 {
  bottom: 0
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="el el1">
    1
  </div>

  <div class="el el2">
    2
  </div>

</div>


<div class="el el3">
  3
</div>
```

Comment: They also should be draggable in the future

Comment: It will remain draggable in the future as you can see from snippet

Comment: And you can position them wherever you want

Comment: Yeah, missed that, thank you, that would work for shown case

Answer (score 2):

Try using grid like below:

```css
.el {
  resize: both;
  overflow-y: auto;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  /* the width / height here */
  grid-template-columns:100px 100px;
  grid-auto-rows:100px;
  gap: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="el">
    1
  </div>

  <div class="el">
    2
  </div>

  <div class="el">
    3
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add one `wrapper-div` and give it fixed `width` and `height`:

```css
.el{
  resize: both;
  overflow-y: auto;
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.wrapper-div{
  margin: 10px;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="wrapper-div">
    <div class="el">
      1
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="wrapper-div">
    <div class="el">
      2
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="wrapper-div">
  <div class="el">
    3
  </div>
</div>
```